# box plot not appearing in Google Colab

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

Trying to create a simple Box Plot using Google Colab for my Intro Python class. It is not appearing as I would like it. You can see my code and output below. I read in a file on NBA statistics, and my box plot would be based on a variable called "SHOT_CLOCK".

**So far what I have:**

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('file path')

plt.boxplot(df['SHOT_CLOCK'], vert=False)
plt.title('Box Plot for SHOT_CLOCK')
plt.xlabel('Shot Clock')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
In your example you are passing a Series object, try this way

```
plt.figure()
plt.title('Box Plot for SHOT_CLOCK')
plt.xlabel('Shot Clock')
df.boxplot(column='SHOT_CLOCK')
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you add the following Import to your code it will work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('classic')
%matplotlib inline
```

Comment: usually an explanation is helpful to the person asking the question, thx.